# Jquery wrap similar content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I'd like to solve with jQuery but I'm unsure of how to go about it. I have a list of `div`s with attribute `data-content` repeated.

```
<div class="element" data-content="string one">
    <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string one">
    <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string one">
    <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string two">
    <p>two</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string two">
    <p>two</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>
```

NOW: https://jsfiddle.net/L5a0netr/

I'm trying to wrap the `div`s that share the same `data-content` attribute in a parent element, like so:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>string one</h2>
    <div class="element" data-content="string one">
        <p>one</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element" data-content="string one">
        <p>one</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <h2>string two</h2>
    <div class="element" data-content="string two">
    <p>two</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element" data-content="string two">
        <p>two</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <h2>string three</h2>
    <div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
    </div>

    <div class="element" data-content="string three">
        <p>three</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle of what it would look like after the change: https://jsfiddle.net/mxcjmdf8/

Answer (score 0):

You gotta create a new element to wrap and put every element inside it, this will do exactly what you want:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<h2>string one</h2>";
$('[data-content="string one"]').each(function(){
        div.appendChild(this);
})
div.className = "wrap";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Then you do it for each wrap you wanna create.

This is the generated html:

[image]

Finally, here's it working:

```js
// STRING ONE
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<h2>string one</h2>";
$('[data-content="string one"]').each(function(){
  div.appendChild(this);
})
div.className = "wrap";
document.body.appendChild(div);

// STRING TWO
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<h2>string two</h2>";
$('[data-content="string two"]').each(function(){
  div.appendChild(this);
})
div.className = "wrap";
document.body.appendChild(div);

// STRING THREE
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = "<h2>string three</h2>";
$('[data-content="string three"]').each(function(){
  div.appendChild(this);
})
div.className = "wrap";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```css
.element {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrap {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element" data-content="string one">
    <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string one">
    <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string one">
    <p>one</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string two">
    <p>two</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string two">
    <p>two</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>

<div class="element" data-content="string three">
    <p>three</p>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm4tT.png)